# Encoding using SHA256 with RSA

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key

I'm attempting to authorize with the Google Data API as a service in a language for which there isn't any client library. The crux is in how to generate the signature. To do this I have to encode a string using "SHA256 with RSA".

I have it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784022/how-to-encrypt-data-using-rsa-with-sha-256-as-hash-function-and-mgf1-as-mask-ge) that it shouldn't be "terribly difficult" however I cannot find a description of the procedure? Anyone knows?

(The language does have a function to generate SHA256 hash codes.)

Comment: What language are you actually using? And, please also specify which auth procedure Google Data API uses.

Comment: Please provide a link to the spec of what you want to implement. RSA+SHA256 isn't enough to fully describe the scheme.

Comment: @CodesInChaos This is the description, is it enough? "Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) with the private key obtained from the API console." (I mean that PKC... part)

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky Mathematica. oAuth 2.0 with a service account: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 requires RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN, which is described in RFC 3447.
Just check section 9.2 of this RFC - you need just add some formatting to the hash of your message.