RSA using EME-OAEP padding with SHA-256 as hash function
I've been automating a login that encrypts the password on the client with the WebCrypto API before it is sent out.
Specifically, it's using RSA-OAEP and basically follows the examples from the MDN github:
let key = window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "spki", binaryDer,
    { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256" },
    true, ["encrypt"]
);

let ciphertext = window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    { name: "RSA-OAEP" },
    key, cleartext
);

I would have liked to do this in perl, but Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA only supports

EME-OAEP padding as defined in PKCS #1 v2.0 with SHA-1, MGF1

...and I neither see a way to change the hash function for the padding, nor did I find another module for the job.
So I had to resort to calling the openssl binary and encrypt the password like so:
openssl pkeyutl -in cleartext.txt -encrypt -pubin -inkey key.pem \
    -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 \
    -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256

This works, however I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this with perl only.

Possibly Crypt::PK::RSA? Never used it, but the linked documentation suggests it supports oaep and sha-256

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55305464/4756299 might be informative.  I suspect the $lparam in Crypt::PK::RSA's my $ct = $pk->encrypt($message, 'oaep', $hash_name, $lparam); can be set to something to set MGF1 to SHA256.  It might even be as simple as an rsa_mgf1_md:sha256 string value.

@AndrewHenle: The frigging $lparam is the damn label, a thing never used but causing confusion and clogging APIs for decades.

@Shawn Excellent, that works out indeed. If you put it up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Since Shawn hasn't responded, I'm answering this myself.
His suggestion to use Crypt::PK::RSA was spot on. This library is absolutely fantastic: It supports the wanted algorithmic variants, has no dependencies at all and covers a huge array of cryptographic methods. Highly recommended.
For the use case outlined in my question; this is how to implement it:
use strict;
use Crypt::PK::RSA;
use MIME::Base64;

my $pubkey = <<EOKEY;
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHlYKg9DeHB3/dY1D9WCyJTnl5
vEzAXpUOL9tDtdPUl96brIbbdMLooO1hKjsq98kLs1q4vOn/pxvzk0BRwhiu7Vvb
VUjAn/2HHDDL0U1utqqlMJhaffeLI3HEq5o/lSMFY7sSkZU/E4YX1yqAN0SE7xfK
B2uzcNq60sMIfp6siQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOKEY

my $pk = Crypt::PK::RSA->new(\$pubkey);
my $cleartext = 'pAsSwOrD';
my $ciphertext = encode_base64( $pk->encrypt($cleartext, 'oaep', 'SHA256', ''), '' );

print $ciphertext."\n";

